# Достать POST из AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

При нажатии одной из 300 кнопок, должен передаваться параметр аяксом.

Код:

```
$(document).on('click', '.lot-not-finished .lottery-member.empty, .lot-not-finished .take-part-btn', function() {
    var place = $(this).data('place');
    ajax({thisPage: true, place: place}, function (data) {
        $('.user-balance').text(data.balance);

        $.notify(data.msg, "success");

        FULL_LOT.myPlacesCount++;
        $('.myPlacesCount').text(FULL_LOT.myPlacesCount + n2w(FULL_LOT.myPlacesCount, SLOTS_TEXT));

        MyLotsManager.add(FULL_LOT.info, 0);
    }, false);

    return false;
});
```

Сама функция AJAX:

```
function ajax(data, success, error) {
    var url = data.thisPage ? '' : '/ajax';
    delete data.thisPage;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data || {},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                success && success(data)
            }
            else {
                if(data.msg) $.notify(data.msg, "error");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            $.notify(LANG['ajaxError'], "error");
            console.log(data);
            console.log(error);
            error && error()
        }
    })
}
```

Я уже и папку на сервере создал /ajax и положил туда index.php вписав в него всякого .... 
Затем сделал редирект со скрипта на папку ajax.. Не могу понять, получает ли мой PHP файл значение или нет.

Я уже засовывал туда:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['place']
$msg = 'chetko';
echo 'success';
$success = true;
echo $msg;
echo json_encode($msg);
echo 'chetko';
$status = 'success';
echo json_encode($status);
echo $status;
echo json_decode($status);

echo '111';
?>
```

Кто может мне объяснить, что должно находиться в моем PHP файле, чтобы я все-таки получил это значение place ? Аяксом оно отправляется - я вижу в консоли его, при нажатии на кнопку.
Но дальше ничего не происходит и я получаю ошибку.

Уже почти 2 часа мучаюсь, и не могу понять, принимает ли мой PHP вообще что-то, и как отдать аяксу обратно ответ, что он принял.. :(

Comment: `Аяксом оно отправляется - я вижу в консоли его, при нажатии на кнопку.` скрин структуры запроса покажите.

Comment: Мораль -- сначала проверяйте, какая от вашего запроса сетевая активность. В браузерах есть средства, показывающие запросы, с заголовками и прочим.

Answer (score 1):

Меня смущает вот что

```
ajax({thisPage: true, place: place}, function (data) { ...
```

а потом

```
var url = data.thisPage ? '' : '/ajax';
```

получается у вас пустой url передается, то есть запрос идет к index.php в корне сайта, а не в папке /ajax. Советую полностью проаисывать url. Заведите файл `ajax/ajaxpool.php` и соовтветсвующий `var url = "/ajax/ajaxpool.php";`
Это для начала.

Далее вы пишите, что формат передаваемых данных - json. Ну так лучше и кодируйте (сериализуйте) свой объект в json

```
...
data: JSON.stringify(data) || "{}",
...
```

Также этот JSON надо на сервере распознать. Делается это так

```
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input'); // все входные данные
 $data = json_decode($json, true); // true - в  ассоциативный массив, а не объект
```

Если вы хотите использовать `$_POST['place']`, то надо передавать данные не в формате JSON, а в формате `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - форма html форм. В этом формате строка выглядит так:

```
thisPage=true&place='myplace'
```

то есть пары `имя1=значение1&имя2=значение2`

Ну и наконец, чтобы понять работает ли скрипт, можно просто писать что-нибудь в файл. Например:

```
file_put_contents("log.txt", "Скрипт по крайней мере запустился");
```

Если будут доп вопросы - пишите в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы указали в запросе `dataType: 'json'`, то и отдавать следует валидный JSON:

```
print json_encode(array(
    "status" => "ok",
    "POST" => $_POST
))
```