# Как отправить данные из формы серверу через jQuery.post()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Научился отправлять данные с сервера в браузер пользователя, но никак не могу научиться отдавать данные из формы серверу!

Сейчас я пытаюсь сделать нажатие кнопки без обновления страницы.Чтобы пользователь  нажал на кнопку и получил какие то данные без перезагрузки.
В это на сервер уходит "нажата кнопка N"
А на сервере описаны действия после нажатия каждой кнопки и возвращаются какие то данные. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, отправить какую кнопку нажал юзер через `jQuery.post()`

P.S.: Через `jQuery.ajax()` можно, но там не совсем понятно, официальная документация описывает все функции которые есть в аджакс и не понятно что тебе из них тебе нужно.

```
<div class="buttons">
    <form id="buttons" action='action.php'>
        <button id="batman" name='bets' class='btn'> я бэтмен! </button>
        <button id="groot" name='tree' class='btn'> я грут! </button>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
     $('#batman').click(function(){
        $('#buttons').hide();
        var vybor = 1;
        startpost(vybor);
    });
    $('#groot').click(function(){
        $('#buttons').hide();
        var vybor = 2;
        startpost(vybor);
    }); //чтобы не использовать два раза надо юзать serialize(), но из примеров не понятно как собирать данные из кнопок. 
    function vybor(na_vhod) {
        $.post ("action.php", //тут надо выдовать входящие но как?
            function(data){
                alert(data.na_vyhod1);
                alert(data.na_vyhod2);
            }, "json" );
    }
</script>

<?// это например  php файл на сервере
        $na_vhod = $_POST["na_vhod"];//входящие данные. тут как я понял должен быть дэкод
        $na_vyhod1 = $na_vhod;
        $na_vyhod2 = $na_vhod;
        echo json_encode(array("na_vyhod1"=>"$na_vyhod1","na_vyhod2"=>"$na_vyhod2")); // исходящие
    ?>
```

Comment: Уточните, что именно вы хотите послать на сервер. Кстати js код у вас не завернут в тег - это опечатка или у вас действительно так? Напишите, что вы хотите получить - исправьте для этого ответ, а в комментарии напишите: "@RussCoder обновил ответ".

Comment: @RussCoder обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам простенький скрипт на js

```
$('#batman').click(function() {
    var data = "text=batman&button=batbut"; // данные в формате html форм
    $.post("action.php", data, function(text){ alert(text); });    
});
```

Вот `action.php`

```
<?php echo "Вы нажали на {$_POST['button']} и прислали текст {$_POST['text']}"; ?>
```

C JSON там посложнее. Надо декодировать его на стороне сервера. Тут почитайте [мой ответ.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454937/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-post-%D0%B8%D0%B7-ajax/454963#454963)

UPD1: С сервера приходит текст, а его можно трактовать как угодно. Если массив приходит то нужен json, но это тот же текст. А так просто надо вывать `var array = JSON.parse(text)` чтобы получить объект-массив.

Comment: я немного не понял function(text), если тут массив пришедший с сервера, то как с ним работать? как я понял нужен json потому что потом будет не одна кнопка, а несколько последовательных нажатий, а данные с сервера приходят разные и много и отправляются в  разные элементы. я пытаюсь писать игру)

Comment: @ЖалгасАжибаев ну так научитесь хоть как-то это делать для начала. Я ссылку дал, если там не поймете как работать с json, тогда пишите. Обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо, попробую помучаться)

Comment: научился, благодарю вас, могу как нибудь поравить вам карму?

Comment: @ЖалгасАжибаев примите мой ответ. Для этого отметьте его галочкой (под рейтингом).