# Возможно ли отправить данные на сервер без form?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

Добрый день!
Вот мой код HTML:

```
    <div class="page__question">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="question__item" data-answear="A">Вариант А</li>
                            <li class="question__item" data-answear="Б">Вариант Б</li>
                            <li class="question__item" data-answear="В">Вариант В</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

<div class="page__transition">
<a href="#" class="btn">продолжить</a>
<div>
```

Возможно ли как-то передать значение которые находятся в "data-answear" без тега form? 
Спасибо!

Comment: Можно. Получаете необходимые значения в переменную и отправляете ее как обычно c помощью  AJAX

Comment: Можно использовать метод jQyery.ajax, как предложили в этом ответе: [Как отправить данные из формы серверу через jQuery.post()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457292/Как-отправить-данные-из-формы-серверу-через-jquery-post). Это наверное не совсем дубликат, скорее отправная точка.

Comment: Оффтоп `answer`, а не `answear`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно послать XHR или AJAX  а получить данные можно через Jq селектор или прям через дом селектор

```
$('#id_element').data('answear') // return value data-answear
```

только проставте своим

```
<li class="question__item">
```

id или уникальные классы чтоб в cелекторе могли получить значение